# python webkit with proxy support

Tags: python, webkit

I am writing a python script for scraping a webpage. I have created a webkit webview object and used the open method for loading the url. But I want to load the url through a proxy.
How can i done this ? How to integrate webkit with proxy? which webkit class support proxy?

Answer (score 4):

try below code snippets. (reference from [url](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/issues/detail?id=53))

```
import gtk, webkit
import ctypes
libgobject = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0')
libwebkit = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so.1')
libsoup = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so.1')
libwebkit = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libwebkit-1.0.so')

proxy_uri = libsoup.soup_uri_new('http://127.0.0.1:8000') # set your proxy url

session = libwebkit.webkit_get_default_session()
libgobject.g_object_set(session, "proxy-uri", proxy_uri, None)

w = gtk.Window()
s = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
v = webkit.WebView()
s.add(v)
w.add(s)
w.show_all()

v.open('http://www.google.com')
```

Hope, it could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QApplicationProxy if you're on pyqt or this snippet if you're using pygi:

```
from gi.repository import WebKit
from gi.repository import Soup

proxy_uri = Soup.URI.new("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
session = WebKit.get_default_session().set_property("proxy-uri")
session.set_property("proxy-uri",proxy_uri)
```

References:
[PyGI](https://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/issues/detail?id=53)
[PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897293/how-to-make-request-through-proxy-in-pyqt4)

Answer (score 1):

How about a solution that's already made?

[PyPhantomJS](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs) is a minimalistic, headless, WebKit-based, JavaScript-driven tool. It is written in PyQt4 and Python. It runs on Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X.

It gives you access to a full headless WebKit browser, controllable via scripts written in JavaScript, with the ability to do various things, amongst which is screen scraping and proxy support. It uses the command line.

You can see the API [here](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs/wiki/Api_reference).

* When I say screen scraping, I mean you can either scrape page content, or even save page renders to a file. There's even a screen scraping JS library already written [here](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/pjscrape).

Comment: Looking forward to trying this!

Comment: I'm afraid to note that the project author isn't able to maintain the project anymore. :/ PhantomJS will work just as well, just that it isn't Python, and you can't make plugins for it. Hopefully someone will step up and take over maintainer-ship of the project..