# How can I configure proxy settings using pure python with pywebkit

Tags: python, proxy, webkit

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915840/python-webkit-with-proxy-support) while looking for an answer, but it uses ctypes to accomplish proxy configuration. Is there a way to do it with pure python, or is ctypes the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug report on the upstream bug tracker that has a patch to add a `set_proxy` function to the `webkit` module.

As of now, it's not present in a released version, but building from git should allow it to be used.

http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/issues/detail?id=53