# How to make request through proxy in PyQt4? - I saw the answer but not sure where to put the code

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm basically trying to scrap a site using PyQt to be able to load the Javascript and I'm trying to do the request through proxy in PyQt4. I saw it works for the guy who asked on this answered question: [How to make request through proxy in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897293/how-to-make-request-through-proxy-in-pyqt4) but I cannot make it work, I'm not sure where to add the information suggested in the answer:

```
old_manager = self.page().networkAccessManager()
new_manager = MyNetworkAccessManager(old_manager)
self.page().setNetworkAccessManager(new_manager)
```

Any idea how to make this code complete?

I have tried something like that:

```
import sys 
import socket
import requests
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MyNetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self):
        QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
        proxy = QNetworkProxy('HTTP','179.179.253.147', '8080') 
        self.setProxy(proxy)

class MySettings(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        old_manager = self.page().networkAccessManager()
        new_manager = MyNetworkAccessManager(old_manager)
        self.page().setNetworkAccessManager(new_manager)
        self.setPage(MySettings())   
        self.loadProgress.connect(self._progress)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.doc = self.page().currentFrame()

    def _progress(self, progress):
        print progress

    def _loadFinished(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(self.doc.toHtml()), 'lxml')
        print soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
br = Browser()
url = QUrl('https://www.example.com')
br.load(url)
br.show()
app.exec_()
```

But is returns an error saying:

> "`__init__()` takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"  on the line
>   new_manager = MyNetworkAccessManager(old_manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass the old manager as an argument, you must change:

```
old_manager = self.page().networkAccessManager()
new_manager = MyNetworkAccessManager(old_manager)
self.page().setNetworkAccessManager(new_manager)
```

to

```
new_manager = MyNetworkAccessManager()
self.page().setNetworkAccessManager(new_manager)
```

Also Change:

```
proxy = QNetworkProxy('HTTP','179.179.253.147', '8080')
```

to:

```
proxy = QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy, QString("179.179.253.147"), 8080)
```

Comment: If I change my code to:

   ` class Browser(QWebView):
        def __init__(self):
            QWebView.__init__(self)
            new_manager = MyNetworkAccessManager()
            self.page().setNetworkAccessManager(new_manager)
            self.setPage(MySettings())   
            self.loadProgress.connect(self._progress)
            self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
            self.doc = self.page().currentFrame()`

Comment: It returns an error on the line:

    proxy = QNetworkProxy('HTTP','179.179.253.147', '8080') 

Error:

arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QNetworkProxy(): too many arguments
QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy.ProxyType, hostName: QString = QString(), port: int = 0, user: QString = QString(), password: QString = QString()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: Ok, I have no errors now, but it is not using the proxy for the request. I'm testing different ip/port from this site: https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-fr/ and if I try to load for example the "www.google.com" it should load the google france if I'm using an proxy ip from france, but it is not, it is loading google from my country, which means it is not using the new proxy for request. =(

Comment: Thank you, I think it works now I have changed the order where to put the code you suggested me and it works!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, yes I did mark your answer as correct. I think I need to add a wait timer to load the page in order to be able to load the page correctly but I'm not sure how. I have opened a question if you can help me please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092488/when-trying-to-load-a-page-using-proxy-and-pyqt-it-returns-a-empty-html-sctructu